# Bash alias autocomplete (with tab key) inserts a \ character while auto completing

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete, debian, alias

OS: Debian 5.10.0-10-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.84-1 (2021-12-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
Hardware: 1 Core, 2GB RAM, VPS ( Cloud server)

Example:

```
alias defined
@syslog='sudo less +F /var/log/syslog'
```

If I manually type in the complete alias i.e. @syslog - then it executes fine.

However, if I only type a few characters like @sys or @sysl or @syslo and then press  key to auto complete, the command is autocompleted and looks like @syslog

This command does not execute as it now has the '' character embedded automatically.

The same issue also happens with another alias like

```
!syslog='sudo less +F /var/log/syslog'    //This is auto completed as \!syslog
```

However, if I do not use any special character in my alias
For example

```
mylog='sudo less +F /var/log/syslog'
```

Then  auto complete works absolutely fine

---

This behaviour is only seen on this particular VPS.
I have another VPS (hosted on a different provider) with the same setup and OS, and at least a dozen of my aliases defined as @xxxxx work fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to  remove `@` from `COMP_WORDBREAKS`?

Comment: bash does not allow spaces around the "="

Comment: @stark spaces is just a typo in my question. The actual file (.bash_aliases) does not contain spaces. I will fix my question.

Comment: @Fravadona 
I tried echo $COMP_WORDBREAKS and it does have the @

Could you please elaborate? Could you please help - Where is COMP_WORDBREAKS defined? Which file, etc? How do I remove the @ symbol?

Comment: Have you consider and tried using a function instead?

Comment: I can fix it by adding this line to .bash_rc 
COMP_WORDBREAKS="${COMP_WORDBREAKS//@}"

… but does anyone know where this is actually defined? Which file ?

Comment: `const char *rl_basic_word_break_characters = " \t\n\"\\'\`@$><=;|&{(";` in `lib/readline/complete.c`.

Answer (score 0):

The above issue was happening as the bash-completion package was not installed in the debian instance.

The above problem is now resolved by

`sudo apt install  bash-completion`